# Paragraph counting java program

Tags: java

My program will not output the correct number of paragraphs in a text. Please help
me in finding my errors! I used a separate method at the very bottom (paraCounter) in order to calculate this.

expected output: 4 (according to text below)
I keep getting: 5

Thank you!

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class WordStats1 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader("data.txt"));

        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(
                "newfile.txt"));

        int lineNum = 0;
        int wordCount = 1;
        int charCount = 0;
        int paraCount = 0;
          boolean key = true;  

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {

        String line;
        line = input.nextLine();
        lineNum++;
        wordCount += getWords(line);        
        charCount += (line.length());
        if (!line.isEmpty()){ 
             key = false; 
        }
        if (!key)
            paraCount += getPara(line);

        }

        System.out.println(lineNum + "  line(s)"); 
        System.out.println(wordCount + " word(s)");
        System.out.println(charCount + " character(s)");
        System.out.println(paraCount + " paragraph(s)");  
        input.close();
        output.close();

        System.out.print("File written.");

    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("There was an error opening one of the files.");
    }
}

public static int getWords(String line) {
    String str[] = line.split((" "));
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i].length() > 0) {
            count++;

        }

    }
    return count;

}
public static int getPara(String line){  
    int count = 0; 
    if(line.isEmpty()) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}




}
```

THE TEXT:
Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent, a new nation, conceived in
Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.

Now   we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any nation so conceived and so
dedicated, can long endure. We are met on a great battle-field of that war. We have come to dedicate a
portion of that field, as a final resting place for those who here gave their lives that that nation might
live. It is altogether fitting and proper that we should do this.

But,    in a larger sense, we can not dedicate -- we can not consecrate -- we can not hallow -- this ground.
The brave men, living and dead, who struggled here, have consecrated it, far above our poor power to add
or detract. The world will little note, nor long remember what we say here, but it can never forget
what they did here. It is for us the living, rather, to be dedicated here to the unfinished work which
they who fought here have thus far so nobly advanced. It is rather for us to be here dedicated to the great
task remaining before us -- that from these honored dead we take increased devotion to that cause for which
they gave the last full measure of devotion -- that we here highly resolve that these dead shall not have
died in vain -- that this nation, under God, shall have a new birth of freedom -- and that government of
the people, by the people, for the people, shall not perish from the earth.

Abraham Lincoln
November 19, 1863

Comment: Is there a problem? What is your definition of a paragraph? What does the input look like and what are you getting as the output?

Comment: you also provide expected and observed output

Comment: Are you missing a += on paraCount?

Comment: So it does output a number but the wrong amount? Can you declare that wrong amount>

Comment: it outputs the wrong amount and I cannot figure out why. I was hoping you could look at my method getPara and figure it out

Comment: first, answer the question asked by @MxyL

Comment: a paragraph is separated by two more blank lines . The expected outcome is 4 but I keep getting 0

Comment: The input is a separate file text specifically the Gettysburg address

Comment: I have posted the inputted text in the question above

Comment: I copy and pasted the exact code from my program and ran it again and it is returning a 5

Answer (score 1):

[Scanner.nextLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) returns the line excluding any newline characters. Hence you won't find `\r\n` in the string.

I would assume that a paragraph is defined as one or more lines ending in one of `.!?"`.

```
public static int getPara(String line) {
   return line.matches(".*[\\.\\?\\!\"]$) ? 1 : 0:
}
```

and of course incrementing the paraCount.

```
paraCount += getPara(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

As your code is right now `paraCount` can only be 1 or 0. You need to change

```
paraCount = getPara(line);
```

to

```
paraCount += getPara(line);
```

Also change your paragraph detection to this

```
public static int getPara(String line){
    int count = 0; 
    if(line.isEmpty()) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Change to this

```
if (key)
    paraCount += getPara(line);
```

Comment: Please try to avoid back-and-forth conversations in the comments.

Comment: @BoltClock Can't start a chat with someone under 20 reputation. I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your input looks like, but getPara is always going to return 0.  You read a single line and pass it to getPara. In getPara the str array will always contain one element since you are attempting to split on "\r\n".  You then only increment count if str.length > 1, which it never will be, so count is never incremented and the method will always return 0 (zero).

Comment: How should I fix this?

Comment: I would do what dcharms suggests, that is only increment the paragraph count when an empty line is encountered.

Comment: I should add that there are some "edge cases" to consider, e.g. if the file starts or ends with blank lines, or a paragraph is separated by two or more blank lines, but hopefully that is enough to get you started.

Comment: I have an idea to do if statements in the format of current line has text and previous line doesn't have text then don't increment etc